# How to filter table with class name in html?

Tags: html, django

If class = "node focused" , how can i filter the data with its id in table table-bordered table-sm table-active in base.html

i want to see deatils only selected node in my table. {d.1} = div id

```
<div id="TEM01" data-parent="ATK" class="node focused"><div class="title" style="width:200px"><i class="oci oci-leader symbol"></i>ATK</div>


<div id="TEM02" data-parent="ATK" class="node"><div class="title" style="width:200px"><i class="oci oci-leader symbol"></i>ATK</div>
```

**chart.js below**

```
    nodeClickHandler: function (event) {
      this.$chart.find('.focused').removeClass('focused');
      $(event.delegateTarget).addClass('focused');
    },
```

**css below**

```
.orgchart .node.focused {
  background-color: rgba(217, 83, 79, 0.8);
}
```

**base.html below.**

```
  <body>
  <div id="chart-container"></div>
      {% block content %}
      {% endblock %}

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery.orgchart.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.js' %}"></script>
  


  <div id=" row justify-content-md-center">
      <div class="col-sm">
          <h5 align="center"><i><span style="background-color: #262626"
                                      class=" badge badge-info">Node Information   </span></i>


          </h5>
          <table class="table table-bordered table-sm table-active">
              <tr>
                  <th>DVS</th>
                  <th>DWH</th>
                  <th>AO_Trap</th>
                  <th>BO_Trap</th>
                  <th>Info</th>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                 
                <tbody>
                  {% for d in alltables %}
                  <tr>
                      <td>{{d.1}}</td>
                      <td>{{d.1}}</td>
                      <td>{{d.2}}</td>
                      <td>{{d.3}}</td>
                  </tr>
                  {% endfor %}
                  </tbody>

              </tr>

          </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize JavaScript/jQuery to adjust the table according to the chosen node with class "node focused." This can be done by filtering the table based on the ID of the selected node. Check out this example to see how it's done:

Add the table update functionality by attaching an event listener that responds to node clicks. To achieve this, you need to adjust the code in your current JavaScript file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Add a click event listener to the chart nodes
    $('#chart-container').on('click', '.node', function(event) {
      // Remove the 'focused' class from all nodes
      $('.node').removeClass('focused');

      // Add the 'focused' class to the clicked node
      $(this).addClass('focused');

      // Get the ID of the selected node
      var selectedNodeId = $(this).attr('id');

      // Filter the table rows based on the selected node ID
      $('table.table-bordered tr').hide();
      $('table.table-bordered td:contains(' + selectedNodeId + ')').parent().show();
    });
  });
</script>
```

1. Each row in your table on base.html needs an ID attribute, so make sure to add that.
2. To modify the structure of the table body, get creative and play around with different options.
3. Make sure to test out your changes to ensure they're working properly.

here is the html modified code.
https://pastebin.com/ssY2xRyS
(was not able to paste the html here.)

Only table rows that contain the clicked node's ID in the first column will be shown after the "focused" class is added to the node in the chart. This is how filtering works. The remaining rows that don't have the selected ID will be concealed.

Comment: could you share html code, i tried but it isn't working